# Can I get a 50cc moped in France on a British provisional licence?

Tags: france, driving

I am currently on a gap year in France/Switzerland. I don't drive and it has proven murder to cycle everywhere. I do have a British provisional licence.

Comment: The situation as described is currently an ex-pat issue. BUt I think that it could equally effect a temporary visitor. Thoughts?

Comment: My understanding is that provisional licenses, learners permits etc (different countries have different names) don't normally have any international validity. So I expect you would have to get whatever French paperwork is required for learning to drive a moped.

Comment: In my understanding this is a case for expats and voting to close as such. However there should be chance to get a provisional licence, inquiries need to be made with the local Swiss/French authorities.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain your provisional licence does not have any validity anywhere outside of the UK. However, [this site](http://www.scooter-rental-paris.com/index_fichiers/scooterrental.htm) says you can rent without a licence if aged over 23.

[This site](http://www.leftbankscooters.com/v02/faqs-2) allows you to rent a 50cc moped if aged over 20 but must have had a car licence for 2 years.

[This site](http://parisbyscooter.com/vespa-rental-paris-france/) states:

> to drive a 50cc scooter in France, the driver must be at least 18
>   years old. If the driver is born after 1988, he must be in possession
>   of a current car driving licence. If the driver is born in 1988 or
>   before, no driving licence is required.

Since you're doing a gap-year, it sounds like you might be too young to satisfy these conditions.

Comment: I read something about an AM licence allowing persons of 14+ to legally drive mo-peds... Have you come across that? Or is it false information? Thank you for your help!!

Comment: https://www.justlanded.com/english/France/Articles/Travel-Leisure/Motorcycles-in-France - says you can get a licence at 14 after passing a test. Not sure you can pass a test before renting though!

Comment: Keep in mind that even for a 50cc you'll need insurance. I was thinking of doing this same thing and I couldn't find insurance for less than 300 euro a year. Dropped the idea then...